# quickbook app/tax/home redirects to /app/salestax?showExistingUI=true

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

on my quickbook app/salestax/home is redirecting to /app/salestax?showExistingUI=true , All the desing that I am getting is diffrent on my purchased account when it redirects to /app/salestax?showExistingUI=true .

I am not sure what I have done wrong or I have mis-configured the settings .

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You should contact QuickBooks support and ask them. This is not a programming problem.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr I have already raised a request Thanks .